# Nested Loops in C programming

Tags: nested-loops

I was wondering how the line "if(!(i%j)) break;" in the code below would be interpreted. Since the "!" symbol is an inverter, does it mean that the bold line in the code below would interpret to saying that "if i mod j is equal to zero, invert and then break out of the loop"

Many thanks

```
int main ()
{
  /* local variable definition */
  int i, j;

  for (i = 2; i < 100; i++) {
    for (j = 2; j <= (i / j); j++)
      if (!(i % j))
        break;
    if (j > (i / j)) printf("%d is prime\n", i);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It says `if (i mod j) == false` and this is only happen when the result of `i mod j` is `0` because all other values are interpreted as `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "if i mod j is equal to zero, invert and then break out of the loop"

Close: *if i mod j equals zero then break*.

```
if ( ! (i % j) ) break;
```

In C, `0` is false and anything else is true. So, when `i % j` is `0`, `! (i % j)` is `1`, and thus true.

Answer (score 0):

In C, an `if (number)` always evaluates to true, unless the number is 0. Therefore, that would evaluate to: if i mod j is equal to 0, basically, if i is a multiple of j.